# How do graph predicted results of a general linear mixed model based on categorical treatment

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, mixed-models

I fit my data to a general linear mixed model with Treatment as a fixed effect and Clutch as a random effect. Here is my code:

```
model<-glmer(cbind(Successes,Failures)~Treatment+(1|Clutch), 
data = cont, family = "binomial")
```

My work deals with sex ratios, and I define a female as a success, and a male as a failure for each observation. I have 4 different treatments. I want to plot (preferably using ggplot) the predicted sex ratio from the model for each treatment, taking clutch into account (with 95% confidence intervals). I realize this is probably a large question, but can anyone help me with the code I would need to do this? I have been searching online for the past few days. Thanks!

Comment: `coef(model)` should get you to the raw estimates…

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do note this is a Q/A forum of volunteers who help programmers answer earnest efforts at code. We don't supply code so your request is off-topic: *but can anyone help me with the code to do this*. Please learn from docs/tutorials, make an effort, and return with specific issues on actual attempt. Good luck!

Comment: Interesting topic! You will be much more likely to get help if you can post sample data (preferably small, representative subsets of `cont`, `Successes`, and `Failures`) in text or code so it can be easily pasted into a fresh R session. Also, please post some type of drawing or description of what your desired output should look like. Finally, some code showing at least a preliminary attempt to create the plot would be desirable.